# Facebook permissions - requesting additional permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-android-sdk

I want to get a list of a users albums names and ids. You need to add the permission `users_photos` for this.

I created a method called `fetchAlbums`, and in it I am requesting additional permissions.  But by the time the permissions dialog pops up, the rest of the method has already executed (without the needed permissions!).

Whats the best way to do this, add the permissions in the `onCreate` of the Activity?

```
private void fetchAlbumsFromFB() {
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
   // make a new async request
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("fields", "id, name");

   new Request(
        session,
        "/me/albums",
        params,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // use response id to upload photo to that album
                //errText.setText("New Album created response: " + response.toString());
                //need to get the newly created album ID.
                try{
                    JSONObject graphResponse =response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Albums " + graphResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    albID = null;
                }
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown where you're asking for the `user_photos` permission so how could we guess what's happening? Also show us where exactly are you calling `fetchAlbumsFromFB`.

Comment: I am calling fetchAlbumsFromFB in the onCreate of the activity. When the activity loads I want to list all the users albums (just album name).  Should I call the permissions in the on create or somewhere else? Problem is, for some reason after the permissions dialogue appears, it goes back to the previous activity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to ask for `user_photos` permission at the starting point, when the user is authenticating the app the first time.

Since it's not an extended/publish permission, it will be asked along with the basic permissions and user wont bother too; else user will see the permission dialogs again and again that could frustrate him.

I guess, in that case this problem will be solved too.

Comment: I didn't realise it was not extended, I'll trt that tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not at work so have to wait until tomorrow! Don't worry if it works I'll mark this as answer..